# How does the order of instructions works inside Scala classes when you override a method

Tags: scala, class, compilation, overriding

I am having my first experience with Scala, experimenting with basic concepts. I made a very simple class, doing shenanigans with overriding `toString` for printing the class instance upon creation:

```
class Person(var firstName: String, var lastName: String) {
  println(this)
  override def toString: String = "Overriden toString"
  println(this)
}
val p = new Person("John", "Smith")
```

I wondered what would happen if I run this code. First `println` before overriding `toString` is supposed to be

> PlatformName$Person@address

if I understand it correctly, which is what you supposed to get when printing a class instance without overriding `toString`. But instead, both prints on construction printed

> Overriden toString.

Why it is so? Does `override` takes the first priority over any other code, ignoring the order, or how does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're defining such a class, you're basically writing the same thing as:

```scala
class Person {

  var firstName: String
  var lastName: String

  // Constructor
  def this(firstName: String, lastName: String) = {
    // Regular constructor member definition
    this.firstName = firstName
    this.lastName = lastName
    // The code you wrote in the class body
    println(this)
    println(this)
  }
  
  override def toString: String = "Overriden toString"
}
```

The code written in the class that is not part of a `def` will be executed when an instance of the class is created (in the *constructor* at run-time).

The `def` of the class are all defined (at compile-time) before you instantiate a class, no matter the order or the `override`.

Comment: I will try to paraphrase it how I did understand the idea:
This code is a proper class definition, the current scala implementation is a "syntax sugar". In this proper form, there is a Constructor part inside `def this() = {}` and the rest is a part of the class. The rest is evaluated on compile-time and the constructor is evaluated on runtime upon instance creation. And in this "syntax sugar" variant a whole class body is a constructor body, and things that don't belong to the constructor are getting evaluated on compile-time and ignored on runtime.

Did I get it right?

Comment: @Jermog Correct!

Comment: yaaay! Although, a bit weird why did they go for this way of making classes, since it's a bit chaotic and not obvious, but this makes creating classes look like defining functions, I guess.

Comment: That's a matter of style but for simple classes it's a simpler/shorter way to define the constructor and the members at the same time. You're right that it can be confusing and thus should be kept for simple usages

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 points of view (from my opinion):
1st is that toString method is evaluated in compile time, but println is when object is created and is done at runtime.
2nd is that when you want to print something, you are implicitly calling `.toString()` method (not only in Scala, same in Java and ...), so the method needs to be evaluated first, and when you call it (implicitly) you happen to see overriden string whenever you println that object.

Comment: Ah, so, you mean it's about what is happening during compiling/runtime and I need to read up what is happening in the first case and what is happening in the second case?

Comment: @Jermog both points of view agree with each other and are not in conflict with each other, what I meant was it happens because of these 2 reasons, and what Gaël J posted as an answer, is actually the same, overriden methods are a part of object that is created and are done and evaluated in compile time, so whenever you want to print that object, you are using the overriden `toString` method